# How can I insert multiple row data into two tables simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Let's say, I've 3 tables A, B and C with following structure.

**Table-A**

```
ID - (int) - PrimaryKey - Identity(auto-generated)
DeptCode - (int)
```

**Table-B**

```
ID - (int) - PrimaryKey - Identity(auto-generated)
Data1 - varchar
AID - Foreign Key from Table-A
```

**Table-C**

```
ID - (int) - PrimaryKey - Identity(auto-generated)
Data2 - varchar
Data3 - varchar
BID - Foreign Key from Table-B
```

**My Question**: How to insert data in 'Table-B' for all records where "DeptCode=101" in 'Table-A' and corresponding to each newly inserted data in 'Table-B' insert 1 row data in 'Table-C' - **In Single query**

The problem can be broken down into two parts, inserting multiple row data in 'Table-B'  from 'table-A' where criteria is satisfied. It can be done using following script.

```
INSERT INTO [TableB] ([Data1]) SELECT  NEWID() FROM TableA WHERE [DeptCode] = 101;
```

For 1 newly added row in Table-B, data can be added to 'Table-C' using following query; not sure how the two queries can be merged - for all the records from 'Table-A'

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @DataID int;
INSERT INTO Table2 ([Data1]) VALUES (NewID());
SELECT @DataID = scope_identity();
INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES ('some data', 'some more data', @DataID);
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `output` clause to manage multiple inserted rows. Something like this.

```
DECLARE @ids table (DataID int);
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO [TableB] ([Data1]) 
output inserted.id into @ids --collect identity id's
SELECT  NEWID() FROM TableA WHERE [DeptCode] = 101;

INSERT INTO Table3 
select 'some data', 'some more data', DataID
from @ids;
COMMIT
```